# Can graphs generated by flot include quadrants II-IV with clearly defined xy-Cartesian axes plus origin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I've started using JS graphing APIs to plot data. I recently found flot and can plot a simple line (y = x + 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d1 = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]];
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.plot($("#GraphScreen"), [d1], {
        xaxis: {
            tickDecimals: 0, font: {
                size: 10, weight: "bold", color: "#000"
            }
        }, 
        yaxis: {
            font: {
                size: 10, weight: "bold", color: "#000"
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The graph looks fine

[image: flot - Line in Quadrant1]

and is plotted in Quadrant I only. However, it is obvious most mathematical functions, when graphed, also have interesting features in Quadrants II-IV!

I changed the dataset to include points that would fall on the line in Quadrants II and III:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d1 = [[-4, -3], [-3, -2], [-2, -1], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]];
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.plot($("#GraphScreen"), [d1], {
        xaxis: {
            tickDecimals: 0, font: {
                size: 10, weight: "bold", color: "#000"
            }
        }, 
        yaxis: {
            font: {
                size: 10, weight: "bold", color: "#000"
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The line is "correct", but the image lacks any clearly-identified Cartesian axes which include an obvious origin:

[image: flot - Axes not identified]

Is there a way to accentuate/make clearly visible the (labeled) axes in flot such that all 4 quadrants are differentiated on the graph? I have read the documentation, searched Stack Overflow (closest I found was this: [flot question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465636/double-axes-in-flot), and searched the web for this topic, but I did not find anything helpful.

Thus far, my solutions are as follows:

1. Live with Quadrant I only (not preferable but take it over not having any plots at all)
2. Hack - Stitch 4 flot containers together using css and js, with each axis appropriately labeled (I'd rather not try this)
3. Try a different web app such JSXGraph (notice that the quadrants are differentiated as shown here: [JSXGraph example](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/examples/)) - this seems like the best option if flot flops

Comment: Did you see this [flot plugin](http://jeff-tian.github.io/jquery.flot.coordinate.js/) ([example here](http://jeff-tian.github.io/jquery.flot.coordinate.js/src/examples/FlotCoordinate.html))? It allows you to add a cartesian-like axis to a flot chart

Comment: No..I didn't. I'm still getting the hang of incorporating APIs. Thank you very much...was ready to try JSXGraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6uHN/1/) to demonstrate how to add the Cartesian-like axis to flot using the [jquery.flot.coordinate.js](http://jeff-tian.github.io/jquery.flot.coordinate.js/) plugin.

After including the plugin script file, adding the following to your options variable does the trick:

```
 coordinate: {
     type: "rectangular"
 }
```

Comment: As soon as I read your comment before I was able to figure out the rest and generate the graph I needed. Regardless, your answer is the best answer....thanks a lot!